# SAM Build only completes successfully with --use-container parameter

Tags: aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I'm developing a Lambda function written in python3.6 to test locally, then deploy to AWS once working. I'm using PyCharm's AWS Serverless Toolkit for this.

SAM build is not building successfully when not including the `--use-container` parameter.

When the 'use container' checkbox is selected, I can build the function, but I don't really understand why it won't work without this checkbox.

My `requirements.txt` file is as follows:

```
sagemaker
boto3
pandas
s3fs
numpy
pathlib
```

#### With parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" build --template C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\template.yaml --build-dir C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build --use-container AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation
2019-08-20 09:23:29 Starting Build inside a container
2019-08-20 09:23:30 Building resource 'AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation'

Fetching lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 Docker container image......
2019-08-20 09:23:32 Mounting C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining as /tmp/samcli/source:ro,delegated inside runtime container

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : ..\..\..\..\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build
Built Template   : ..\..\..\..\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build\template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke -t ..\..\..\..\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build\template.yaml
[*] Package: sam package --s3-bucket <yourbucket> --template-file ..\..\..\..\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build\template.yaml

Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource
```

#### Without parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" build --template C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\template.yaml --build-dir C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation
2019-08-20 09:16:30 Building resource 'AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation'
2019-08-20 09:16:30 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), pyyaml==3.13(wheel), cryptography==2.7(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), pywin32==224(wheel), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist)}
```

#### To help debug this error, I ran the same command with the --debug parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" build --template C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\template.yaml --build-dir C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\.aws-sam\build AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation --debug
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2019-08-20 09:30:14 'build' command is called
2019-08-20 09:30:14 No Parameters detected in the template
2019-08-20 09:30:14 2 resources found in the template
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Found Serverless function with name='AutomatedSageMakerTraining' and CodeUri='.'
2019-08-20 09:30:14 Found Serverless function with name='AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation' and CodeUri='.'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Building resource 'AutomatedSageMakerEvaluation'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Loading workflow module 'aws_lambda_builders.workflows'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'NodejsNpmBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='nodejs', dependency_manager='npm', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'GoDepBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='dep', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'GoModulesBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='modules', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'JavaMavenWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='maven', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Registering workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Found workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Running workflow 'PythonPipBuilder'
2019-08-20 09:30:15 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
2019-08-20 09:30:15 calling pip download -r C:\Users\------\PycharmProjects\AutomatedSageMakerTraining\requirements.txt --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z
2019-08-20 09:31:20 Full dependency closure: {sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), cryptography==2.7(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), requests==2.20.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel), cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), pywin32==224(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), pyyaml==3.13(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), pycparser==2.19(sdist), idna==2.7(wheel), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:31:20 initial compatible: {docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), requests==2.20.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel), cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), idna==2.7(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:31:20 initial incompatible: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:31:20 Downloading missing wheels: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:31:20 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pyyaml==3.13
2019-08-20 09:31:21 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z numpy==1.17.0
2019-08-20 09:31:27 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5
2019-08-20 09:31:28 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pycparser==2.19
2019-08-20 09:31:29 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z scipy==1.3.1
2019-08-20 09:31:39 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z sagemaker==1.37.1
2019-08-20 09:31:40 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z s3fs==0.3.3
2019-08-20 09:31:41 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pathlib==1.0.1
2019-08-20 09:31:42 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z cryptography==2.7
2019-08-20 09:31:44 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z fsspec==0.4.1
2019-08-20 09:31:45 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z texttable==0.9.1
2019-08-20 09:31:46 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z dockerpty==0.4.1
2019-08-20 09:31:47 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z protobuf==3.9.1
2019-08-20 09:31:49 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z cffi==1.12.3
2019-08-20 09:31:51 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pynacl==1.3.0
2019-08-20 09:31:52 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pandas==0.25.0
2019-08-20 09:32:01 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z docopt==0.6.2
2019-08-20 09:32:02 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\-------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z pywin32==224
2019-08-20 09:32:03 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp36m --dest C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z bcrypt==3.1.7
2019-08-20 09:32:04 compatible wheels after second download pass: {docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), requests==2.20.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel), cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), idna==2.7(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:04 Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling True): {protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), docopt==0.6.2(sdist)}
2019-08-20 09:32:04 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\-------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\protobuf3-to-dict-0.1.5.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:07 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\pycparser-2.19.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:10 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\sagemaker-1.37.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:13 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\s3fs-0.3.3.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:16 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:18 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\fsspec-0.4.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:20 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\texttable-0.9.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:23 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\dockerpty-0.4.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:25 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 compatible after building wheels (no C compiling): {docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), requests==2.20.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel), cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), idna==2.7(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:28 Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling False): {protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), docopt==0.6.2(sdist)}
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\protobuf3-to-dict-0.1.5.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\pycparser-2.19.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\sagemaker-1.37.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\s3fs-0.3.3.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\fsspec-0.4.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\texttable-0.9.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\dockerpty-0.4.1.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnbl_t57z\docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
2019-08-20 09:32:28 compatible after building wheels (C compiling): {docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), requests==2.20.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel), cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), idna==2.7(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:28 Final compatible: {cached-property==1.5.1(wheel), docker-pycreds==0.4.0(wheel), asn1crypto==0.24.0(wheel), setuptools==41.1.0(wheel), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), botocore==1.12.211(wheel), jsonschema==2.6.0(wheel), pytz==2019.2(wheel), boto3==1.9.211(wheel), certifi==2019.6.16(wheel), websocket-client==0.56.0(wheel), paramiko==2.6.0(wheel), urllib3==1.24.3(wheel), docker==3.7.3(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), idna==2.7(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), jmespath==0.9.4(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pypiwin32==223(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), docutils==0.15.2(wheel), requests==2.20.1(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), docker-compose==1.24.1(wheel), s3transfer==0.2.1(wheel), colorama==0.4.1(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:28 Final incompatible: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), numpy==1.17.0(wheel), scipy==1.3.1(wheel), cryptography==2.7(wheel), protobuf==3.9.1(wheel), cffi==1.12.3(wheel), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), pandas==0.25.0(wheel), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:28 Final missing wheels: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
2019-08-20 09:32:55 PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\actions.py", line 39, in execute
    self.scratch_dir
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 143, in build_dependencies
    requirements_path, artifacts_dir_path, scratch_dir_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\packager.py", line 212, in build_site_packages
    raise MissingDependencyError(packages_without_wheels)
aws_lambda_builders.workflows.python_pip.packager.MissingDependencyError: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 248, in run
    action.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\python_pip\actions.py", line 42, in execute
    raise ActionFailedError(str(ex))
aws_lambda_builders.actions.ActionFailedError: {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}

Build Failed
2019-08-20 09:32:55 Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'duration': 160781, 'exitReason': 'UserException', 'exitCode': 1, 'requestId': '943b9308-c11b-43e0-9d6d-5bbc984946ad', 'installationId': '0c5d4463-668a-4706-ae40-afd0704d66bd', 'sessionId': '4736e025-2966-4a4b-aeb6-2702fe347779', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'pyversion': '3.6.7', 'samcliVersion': '0.19.0'}}]}
2019-08-20 09:32:55 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443
2019-08-20 09:32:56 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {pyyaml==3.13(wheel), protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5(sdist), pycparser==2.19(sdist), sagemaker==1.37.1(sdist), s3fs==0.3.3(sdist), pathlib==1.0.1(sdist), cryptography==2.7(wheel), fsspec==0.4.1(sdist), texttable==0.9.1(sdist), dockerpty==0.4.1(sdist), pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), docopt==0.6.2(sdist), pywin32==224(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.7(wheel)}
```

It seems for some reason it's not able to resolve compatible dependencies when the --use-container parameter is not set.

I am, fortunately, able to deploy the Lambda functions to AWS inside a container by deploying the template.yaml as a Serverless (CloudFormation) Application, if I don't check this box it fails too. [image: Right click template.yaml] [image: Select build function inside a container]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have an explanation of WHY this works with `--use-container`, but I had the same problem and nobody else seems to be answering this.

It appears that some of the libraries you are trying to use are missing wheel files. It actually says so in the debug message, but it's not easy to find if you don't know what you are looking for. More about wheels at https://pythonwheels.com/.

So, after a few hours of digging, I ran the following command in the terminal:

```sh
pip install wheel
```

After that, I could build, invoke the function locally, and deploy to AWS without the `--use-container` parameter.

Comment: This is still the answer as of aws-sam-cli v0.40.0; the reason behind it is that the package aws-lambda-builders which controls the pip download process looks for a linux-built wheel for each dependency; when there is not one for a given package, it attempts to build a wheel from the raw sdist code - this requires the wheel package, which is not installed as a dependency of SAM. You have to install it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround that may or may not work depending on your particular dependency/dependencies is to **use one of the possibly existing previous versions of your problematic dependency/dependencies**, which as a consequence might (a) have older dependencies that might have wheels on PyPI or (b) lack the problematic dependencies.

For example, the `PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies` error is raised with `jsonschema==3.2.0` because it depends on `pyrsistent` that doesn't currently have wheels on PyPI. However, the error is not produced with `jsonschema==2.6.0` because it doesn't depend on `pyrsistent`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, specifically with `psycopg2`, and `pip install wheel` or `--use-container` did not help.

What I did instead was installing the binary version of the package in question `pip install psycopg2-binary`, and also included `psycopg2-binary` in the `requirements.txt` file.

This solved my problem, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when using `python3.8.8`, installed with `pyenv`. I also found a hint about `wheel` in the debug-output, but it was already installed.

I was able to fix it by upgrading `pip`:

```
/Users/xyz/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you requirements.txt file, I had the same issue but I noticed that the file had an enter <-| in the end of file, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, some package versions might have missing wheel files. In my case, a new version of a package somewhere in the dependency tree was the culprit.
What I did to solve it was to add the previous version of that package explicitly to my requirements.txt file.

so after receiving `Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {greenlet==1.1.0(wheel)}`

I added `greenlet==1.0.0` to my requirements file.